# Dictionary output incorrect after sorting

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to find:

- an average of 3 different scores that different users obtain inside a dictionary
- highest score of each user in alphabetical order
- the highest scores of the workers in my workplace, from highest to lowest.

I have completed all of the code, but the output is wrong.

The text file that I am writing from has now been modified in line with real scenarios:

```
AdamJohnson:11
AdamJohnson:41
AdamJohnson:15
AdamJohnson:18
AdamJohnson:34
AdamJohnson:48 
MichaelJordan:29
MichaelJordan:33
MichaelJordan:46
MichaelJordan:34
DavidSnowman:55
DavidSnowman:35
DavidSnowman:21
DavidSnowman:37
```

The code that I have used to write all the scores to a dictionary, with the last three scores appears as follows:

```
worker_scores = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.deque(maxlen=3))

worker_scores.clear() 


with open('score_names.txt') as f:
    for line in f: 
        worker,score = line.split(":")
        worker_scores[worker].append(int(score))

for worker in sorted(worker_scores):
    print(worker," ".join(map(str,worker_scores[worker])))
```

The outcome of the code above is shown below:

```
AdamJohnson 18 34 48
DavidSnowman 35 21 37
MichaelJordan 33 46 34
```

Which is what I expected, evidently.

Now, the code I have used to arrange the names in alphabetical order is shown:

```
def highscores_pupil(worker_scores):
    d=OrderedDict()

    for k,v in sorted(((i,j.pop()) for i,j in worker_scores.items()),reverse=False):
        d[k]=v

    for k,v in d.items():
        print (':'.join((k,str(v))))
```

Yet when this code is run, the highest score is incorrect. Instead of it being:

```
AdamJohnson:48
DavidSnowman:37
MichaelJordan:46
```

It shows:

```
AdamJohnson:48
DavidSnowman:37
MichaelJordan:34
```

My second block of code to arrange the scores in order of highest to lowest is shown:

```
def highscores_all(worker_scores):
    d=OrderedDict()

    for k,v in sorted(((i,j.pop()) for i,j in worker_scores.items()),reverse=False):
        d[k]=v

    for k,v in sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
        print (':'.join((k,str(v))))
```

The result I expect is:

```
AdamJohnson:48
MichaelJordan:46
DavidSnowman:37
```

Although the incorrect result returns as:

```
AdamJohnson:48
DavidSnowman:37
MichaelJordan:34
```

Finally, to find an average, I used this line of code:

```
def average_all(worker_scores):

   AvgDictName = dict([(key, float(sum([int(i) for i in values])) / len(values)) for key, values in worker_scores.items()])

   for k,v in sorted(AvgDictName.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
       print (':'.join((k,str(v))))
```

Which in fact **does** produce the results I require...

```
MichaelJordan:37.666666666666664
AdamJohnson:33.333333333333336
DavidSnowman:31.0
```

Why do the highest score of each user and the highest scores of all the workers (the first two calculations) come incorrect?

Comment: Just look at `[(i,j.pop()) for i,j in worker_scores.items()]`. There's no reason for your code to produce highest scores.

Comment: It could be a coincidence but.. the unexpected results seem to be the last element of the results given by `for worker in sorted(worker_scores): ..`. 

Also, comments like the ones you mention get flagged, and deleted, and my guess is that the user that posts them continuously, will eventually face the consequences of his action.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because your scores are not sorted and `pop` just returns the last element, thus instead of `pop` you can use `max` in your `sorted` function :

```
for k,v in sorted(((i,max(j)) for i,j in worker_scores.items()),reverse=False):
    d[k]=v
```

Demo:

```
>>> max(collections.deque([33 ,46 ,34]))
46
```